# Tab activity getting crash

Tags: android, android-layout

I am crearing a Tab Activity in my application. I have created `tabHost` Activity but its not working. Due to this activity application is getting crash. Please Help me.
Here is code.

```
package com.examples.deepak.locationcloaker;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;

public class LocationCloakerActivity extends TabActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();//(TabHost)findViewById(id);

        TabSpec tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab1");
        tabSpec.setIndicator("Home");
        tabSpec.setContent(new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class));
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);

        tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab2");
        tabSpec.setIndicator("Search");
        tabSpec.setContent(new Intent(this, SearchActivity.class));
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
    }
}
```

and my xml file is

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="htp://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >


        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/hello" />

    </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```

my manifest.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.examples.deepak.locationcloaker"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".LocationCloakerActivity" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".HomeActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".SearchActivity"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Log cat shows

```
 02-08 16:22:09.208: I/Process(752): Sending signal. PID: 752 SIG: 9
02-08 16:31:28.168: D/AndroidRuntime(786): Shutting down VM
02-08 16:31:28.168: W/dalvikvm(786): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
02-08 16:31:28.198: E/AndroidRuntime(786): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-08 16:31:28.198: E/AndroidRuntime(786): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.examples.deepak.locationcloaker/com.examples.deepak.locationcloaker.LocationCloakerActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #2: You must supply a layout_width attribute.
02-08 16:31:28.198: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
02-08 16:31:28.198: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
02-08 16:31:28.198: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
02-08 16:31:28.198: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
02-08 16:31:28.198: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-08 16:31:28.198: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
02-08 16:31:28.198: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
02-08 16:31:28.198: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-08 16:31:28.198: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-08 16:31:28.198: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
02-08 16:31:28.198: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
02-08 16:31:28.198: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-08 16:31:28.198: E/AndroidRuntime(786): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #2: You must supply a layout_width attribute.
02-08 16:31:28.198: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getLayoutDimension(TypedArray.java:491)
02-08 16:31:28.198: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.setBaseAttributes(ViewGroup.java:3598)
02-08 16:31:28.198: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams.<init>(ViewGroup.java:3678)
02-08 16:31:28.198: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams.<init>(FrameLayout.java:457)
02-08 16:31:28.198: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.generateLayoutParams(FrameLayout.java:423)
02-08 16:31:28.198: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.generateLayoutParams(FrameLayout.java:47)
02-08 16:31:28.198: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
02-08 16:31:28.198: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
02-08 16:31:28.198: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
02-08 16:31:28.198: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:207)
02-08 16:31:28.198: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
02-08 16:31:28.198: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at com.examples.deepak.locationcloaker.LocationCloakerActivity.onCreate(LocationCloakerActivity.java:15)
02-08 16:31:28.198: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
02-08 16:31:28.198: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
02-08 16:31:28.198: E/AndroidRuntime(786):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: Post you LogCat with Exception

Comment: Well! cannot say anything without logCat info. It seems that you haven't declared some of your activities in ' AndroidMainfest.xml '

Answer (score 0):

remove

```
 <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/hello" />
```

from your xml file

TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

```
// Android tab
Intent intentAndroid = new Intent().setClass(this,
        AndroidActivity.class);
TabSpec tabSpecAndroid = tabHost.newTabSpec("Android").setContent(
        intentAndroid);

Intent intentApple = new Intent().setClass(this, AppleActivity.class);
TabSpec tabSpecApple = tabHost.newTabSpec("Ae").setContent(intentApple);

tabHost.addTab(tabSpecAndroid);
tabHost.addTab(tabSpecApple);
tabHost.setCurrentTab(1);
```

**Xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp">
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="5dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```